# Не отображаются элементы в GroupBox'ах при повторном вызове окна с ними (PyQT)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

Пишу програму с графическим интерфейсом через PyQT. Каждый клас реализован в виде окна (QtGui.QWidget). Есть главное меню и из него вызываются остальные окна. Реализовано это, в общем, за следующей схемой:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class A(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Push", self)

    def __call__(self):
    # дизайн елементов
        buttonsLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.button)

        buttonsGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox("Control buttons")
        buttonsGroupBox.setLayout(buttonsLayout)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonsGroupBox)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.resize(200,200)
        self.show()

class Main(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button.clicked.connect(A())
        self.button.setGeometry(60,60,60,60)
        self.resize(200,200)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    menu = Main()
    menu.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Проблема состоит том, что если, например, класс А() вызывается по кнопке с меню впервые, то весь его дизайн отображается правильно, но если закрыть его через кнопку управления окном (крестик), то, при следующем открытии, все его элементы исчезают (остаются только названия GroupBox'ов). Возможно есть какие-то дополнительные методы, которые позволяют настроить корректный многоразовый вызов GroupBox'ов?

Comment: Добавил работающий пример кода. Проблема, видимо, связана с использованием лейаутов, потому что когда пробую использовать абсолютное позиционирование для второго окна, ничего не исчезает при повторном открытии. Наверное, мне неизвестна какая-то функция, которая настраивает лейаут или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: вернее групбоксы.